# Compile each .svelte component file into separate webcomponent .js file

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

How can I compile each .svelte component into separate webcomponent .js file?
for example
DatePicker.svelte -> DatePicker.js
FileUploadArea.svelte -> FileUploadArea.js

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Try esbuild : https://github.com/EMH333/esbuild-svelte

Answer (score 1):

You can create the a new `vite.split.config.js` & use that in the build process & in the `input` array of `rollupOptions` you can define the svelte components paths you want to export. Then build with `-c vite.split.config.js` flag.

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import {svelte} from '@svelte.js/vite-plugin-svelte';

export default defineConfig({
   build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        input: ['./src/lib/Button.svelte'],
      }
   },
   plugins: [
    svelte({
        compilerOptions: {
            customElement: true,
        },
     })
  ]
});
```

You can find more details on the [Log Rocket Blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-web-components-svelte/)